Question about reducing phase delay in filters for microcontroller application
I am trying to design a filter to smooth out some of my sensor data. This is for a control systems application where I have limited phase margin.
I am looking for a solution where I can maintain lower phase addition up until 2000 rad/s, while being able to attenuate my signal.
Can you tell me if there's a practical way of implementing a filter with minimal phase lag in a microcontroller application? Right now, I am trying my luck with a second order Butterworth filter, but I get too much phase delay.
Edit
Below is the bode plot of my digital control system. I want to design a filter with a cut-off frequency of 1000 Hz, while having a phase delay of less than 15 degrees at 318 Hz. I was wondering how feasible this might be. I'd like to have a flat magnitude response and avoid ripples in the passband.


What about a bessel filter?

By definition an IIR Butterworth filter is minimum phase.  If you edit your question with information about the noise spectrum, sampling rate, and desired loop bandwidth, we may be able to help you achieve your larger goal.

You are not going to stabilize that system by putting a low pass filter in the loop.

It is a stable system already - it has an unstable pole, so it's stable as per the Nyquist stability criterion

You can't do better than a minimum phase filter. A first order IIR filter will have a phase of -45 degrees at the crossover, so getting to less than -15 degree at 320 Hz will be tricky.
Turns out at 1st order the type of filter (Butterworth, Chebychef, etc) doesn't matter since they are all the same. For a cutoff of 1kHz (assuming a sample rate of 10 kHz), phase at 318 Hz will be around -19 degrees and the you hit -15 degrees roughly at 275 Hz.
You can push this out a bit by sacrificing some stop band attenuation and not put a zero at Nyquist. For example if you multiply your numerator with $[1.5, 0.5]$ the phase at 318 Hz is -14.5 degree but the attenuation at Nyquist is only -16 dB.
So you can play around with cutoff frequency and stop band attenuation to optimize for your application. There may also be a way to do a least square error FIR design but that's fairly complicated and I don't know if it would be better.

Do you reckon I could make up for the added phase lag through adding phase lead to my system with a lead compensator?
